# Get Ubuntu Software program (snap-store) to refresh catalogue automatically

Tags: 22.04, snap-store

Lately every time I open the Snap Store, it contains nothing but one editor's choice program and, to refresh the cataloue, it is necessary to open a terminal and run

```
$ killall snap-store
$ exit
```

then to open the Snap Store again and wait while the current catalogue is downloaded.  This is tiresome.

Is there any way to get Snap Store to download the catalogue automatically either when the computer is started or when Snap Store is first opened each day?

Comment: It is unclear if you are asking about update notifications or if you are asking about catalog refreshes. They seems like separate issues.

Comment: I'd suggest just using the [Snapcraft website / store](https://snapcraft.io) for now and installing snaps via the command line. The Snap Store app is... imperfect to say the least

Comment: ՕլՁՅԿ, thank you for that suggestion.  I have book-marked the Snapcraft store in my browser and will use that until the Snap Store fixes their catalogue refresh problem.  I don't often install things from the Snap Store, mostly utilities, but it is useful to see what is available on a regular basis.  Thanks again!

Comment: user535733, thanks for your comment.  I have edited my question to make it more clear that it concerns refreshing the catalogue, rather than update notifications.